# what is best way to prepare C# objects in separate methods

Tags: c#

What is better method to use for object preparation logic:

a) with return value

```
List<Users> users = LoadUsers();
users = PrepareUsers(users);
```

b) or with void type

```
List<Users> users = LoadUsers();
PrepareUsers(users)
```

Comment: With void type. There must be a reason to return a value.

Comment: If you ask us to close your question use words like "better". _Better_ in what terms? But even if you'd specify it people will have different opinions. Questions which are "primarily opinion based" are not on-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: I vote B, with the void type

Comment: Looks like an off-topic for SO. Use http://codereview.stackexchange.com if your question is not about a problem with your code but about "what is the best way to write this code".

Comment: @Fedor: a "better" place to ask this is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimSchmelter agree, in this case it fits better

Answer (score 4):

Are you setting properties on existing `User` objects or are you creating new ones?

If you're simply changing existing objects, then there's no reason why you'd want to return them, it's redundant. Worse, it's misleading - the client will *think* his objects were left untouched and that you're creating new objects when in fact you're not.

If you're creating new ones, well then, you obviously need to return them.

Comment: And having functions change objects screams making those functions members...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative b. since you are working with the same user objects, there is no reason to reassign the variable.